# error while opening the default python3 install in raspbian

Tags: python-3

well, i have been using python3.4.2 for sometime on my raspbian os however recently i tried to change the default to 3.7.2. unfortunately i failed to do so... i downloaded it but i couldn't make it default. later, i tried to open the default one and it showed me and error message:

Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/idle3" (No such file or directory)

.... the file is still there but its failing to run. so, what may be the problem?

Comment: Raspbian has been using Python 3.5 for years; Buster now has 3.7.3

Comment: It's unclear what you actually did. You're not supposed to just "download" software, you should install it.